# What is the cost of an additional column

Tags: mysql

I have table `fields` with only 3 columns: `owner_id INT, value VARCHAR(255), type INT`. It is planned that this table will store a lot of data.

I need to add column to store values with big length (TEXT). I see 2 ways.

- Add new column to this table with type TEXT.
- Add new table like this: `CREATE TABLE field_contents(field_id INT, content TEXT)`.

What a better way? What is the cost (drive space, memory, CPU) of an additional TEXT-column if in 99% it will be empty?

Comment: Try both and answer your question yourself (it actually always makes sense to try/research/put some effort **before** you ask here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with adding the `content` column to the original `fields` table, at least from a storage point of view.  `NULL` values in variable length columns in MySQL do not take up any space in the row themselves.  Since `TEXT` is a `BLOB` type, and has a variable length, the empty entries in your table should therefore not be a performance killer for storage.

As to whether the `content` column logically belongs in the `fields` table itself depends on your database design.

Read [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109210/does-an-empty-column-value-occupy-same-storage-space-as-a-filled-column-value) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

if you **really** need this modification just do them

```
ALTER TABLE fields DROP COLUMN old_column
ALTER TABLE fields ADD COLUMN content TEXT
```

Adding new field and removing unused one definitely better than adding new table, at least to manage your BD structure.

Comment: Incomplete due to no explanation !!! You better look into ***Tim Biegeleisen***'s answer.

Comment: what's the point of the cost if you really have to add new column? from my point of view if he will remove unused fields it be good enough

Comment: whether to add a column or a new table is the question and OP is in dilemma. He definitely needs explanation when suggesting some solution. ***... don't worry ...*** makes no sense.

Comment: Adding new field definitely better, at least to manage your DB structure. Am i wrong?

Comment: Well. You did not post supporting statements in the answer. Did you?